# Accessing the last element on a row in a 2D array that is in a structure

Tags: arrays, c, structure

I'm attempting to access the last element on each row of a 2D array that is inside a structure. I'm, attempting to determine if a specific character is in that position, but I can't figure out how to access that specific element.

My *unfinished* code:

```
typedef struct node {
   char grid[MAXGRIDHW][MAXGRIDHW];
   int height;
   int width;
   int parent;
} Node;

bool emptyEnd (Node *b)
{
   int x, y;
   char lastEle = ;

   for (y = 0; y <= b->height; y++) {
      for (x = 0; x <= b->width; x++) {
         if (lastEle == '-') {
            return true;
         } else {
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: C loops run `for (y = 0; y < b->height; y++)`, using `<` and not `<=`.  Something like 99% of the time, using `<=` instead of `<` is a bug.

Comment: This `char lastEle = ;` should have thrown error , did you compile ?

Comment: Also note that you unconditionally return from the function on the first iteration of the inner loop in the first iteration of the outer loop — rendering the loops completely unnecessary.  You probably want to keep `return true;` and remove the `else` clause completely, adding `return false;` after the loop bodies.

Comment: What if I need the loop to run until it is equal to the height of the array?

Comment: The valid elements in the array have indexes 0, 1, ... MAXGRIDHW-1; accessing index MAXGRIDHW is accessing the array out of bounds, leading to undefined behaviour.  That's why `<=` is wrong.

Comment: IrAM - the lastEle part is what I need assistance with, I need that to equal the last element on each row of my array to check it against the if statement in my loop

Comment: So if I change <= to just < that will negate that?

Comment: If you need `lastEle` to be the last element in each row, then you don't need the inner loop at all (the last element in the row is the same regardless of which element in the row you index).  Assuming that you simply mean the element at `b->grid[y][b->width - 1]`, use that.  The `lastEle` variable becomes pointless.

Comment: The `<` instead of `<=` fix sorts out one problem.  There are multiple other problems that also have to be sorted out.  As so often, where there's one bug, there are also others in hiding.

Comment: Is the function supposed to return true if at least one row has a dash in the last column, or if all rows have a dash in the last column, or some other condition?  Explain to us (and hence to yourself) exactly what the function is supposed to do.  Did you consider adding an argument `char c` which specifies the character to look for?  There might be advantages to that flexibility, or it might be superfluous generality.  But the some/all distinction is crucial to getting the code right.

Comment: The function should return true if any of the last column matches the specified char. As if it does it means that another char can take its place as a dash represents empty space. In this program the rows must be filled only by the same character, or by a space, but if a character can go onto the row it must fill up from left to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in comments:

- In C, for loops customarily run `for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)` so that the `limit` elements of an array can all be accessed without stepping outside the bounds of the array (which leads to undefined behaviour).
- Remember, if you have an array `SomeType array[10];`, the valid indexes have values 0..9; `array[10]` is not an element that you can access legitimately (though you can form the address `&array[10]` and make comparisons with it).
- You code for `lastEle` is not valid C.
- Given the requirement that "the function should return true if any of the last column values matches the specified char", your double loop is unnecessary.  You only need to check one character in each row, so iterating over the number of rows is sufficient.
- The original code unconditionally returns from the function on the first iteration of the inner loop in the first iteration of the outer loop — rendering the loops completely unnecessary. You need to keep `return true;` and remove the `else` clause completely, adding `return false;` after the loop bodies.
- The inner loop in the original code is unnecessary.  There is only one last character in each row, so there is no need to check for each character position in the row whether the last character in the row matches a fixed value.

Here is code that works.  It doesn't assume that the grid consists of strings — the byte (`char`) arrays are not necessarily null-terminated.  It doesn't assume that the grid is maximally full (either the `height` or the `width` or both can be smaller than `MAXGRIDHW`).  The search function is parameterized by the character to search for so that the code can be tested searching for different characters.  I kept the `parent` element of the structure even though it plays no useful role in the code.  I used C99 designated initializers, and C99-style `for` loops where the loop variable is defined in the loop control.  I included the `print_grid()` function because I wanted to be able to see that the search was correct.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAXGRIDHW = 6 };

typedef struct node
{
    char grid[MAXGRIDHW][MAXGRIDHW];
    int height;
    int width;
    int parent;
} Node;

static bool emptyEnd(Node *b, char c)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < b->height; y++)
    {
        if (b->grid[y][b->width - 1] == c)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

static void print_grid(const char *tag, const Node *np)
{
    printf("%s: P = %d, H = %d, W = %d\n", tag, np->parent, np->height, np->width);
    for (int r = 0; r < np->height; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < np->width; c++)
            putchar(np->grid[r][c]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Node n =
    {
        .parent = 0, .width = 5, .height = 4,
        .grid =
        {
            { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' },
            { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'z' },
            { 'p', 'p', '*', '*', '-' },
            { '@', '@', '@', '!', '-' },
        },
    };
    char test[] = "-eA";

    print_grid("Test Grid", &n);

    for (int i = 0; test[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (emptyEnd(&n, test[i]))
            printf("At least one last character is '%c'\n", test[i]);
        else
            printf("Not even one last character is '%c'\n", test[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output from the program is:

```
Test Grid: P = 0, H = 4, W = 5
abcde
bcdxz
pp**-
@@@!-
At least one last character is '-'
At least one last character is 'e'
Not even one last character is 'A'
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I took your version of the emptyEnd function but defined the char I'm looking for inside the function and completed this test on it assert(emptyEndOfShelf(&shelf1[1]) == true);  using a grid which is contained in a structure (I used memcpy to pcopy the array into the struct), but the assert fails depsite there being empty spaces in the final column. The only difference between yours and my code is that the char is hardwired into the function: 
char testArr1[3][4] = {{"..."},
                                  {"..."},
                                  {"..."}};

Comment: I'd need to see your code to have a chance of debugging it.  If need be, you can send me email — see my profile, and include 'Stack Overflow' in the subject line and the question URL in the body, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAXGRIDHW 4

typedef struct node {
   char grid[MAXGRIDHW][MAXGRIDHW];
   int height;
   int width;
   int parent;
} Node;

_Bool emptyEnd (Node *b)
{
   int x, y;
   char lastEle = b->grid[MAXGRIDHW-1][MAXGRIDHW-1];
   printf("%c\n", lastEle);  //====> 'p'
   return (lastEle == '-');  
}

int main() {
    struct node n = { .height = 100, .width  = 100 };
    char grid[MAXGRIDHW][MAXGRIDHW] = {{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
                                      {'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'},
                                      {'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'},
                                      {'m', 'n', 'o', 'p'}};
    memcpy(n.grid, grid, sizeof(char) * MAXGRIDHW * MAXGRIDHW);
    printf("%d\n", emptyEnd(&n)); //===> false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it really matter if 2D array is present inside `struct`?

If it does with a little modification you can make this below program work.

Instead of passing the struct variable , pass an array inside the struct.

Hope below is good for your requirement.

```
#define MAX_NUM_OF_LINES 3
#define MAX_NUM_OF_CHARS_PER_LINE 15

bool getTheLastChar(char *str);

int main()
{
    char Arr[MAX_NUM_OF_LINES][MAX_NUM_OF_CHARS_PER_LINE] = {"ABC-","DEFG","HIJ-"};
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<MAX_NUM_OF_LINES; i++)
    {
        if(true == getTheLastChar(Arr[i]))
            printf("there is a - at last in %s\n", Arr[i]);
    }
   return 0;
}

bool getTheLastChar(char *str)
{
    bool retVal = false;
     
    if( str[strlen(str)-1] == '-')
       retVal = true;
     
    return retVal;
}
```